# How to prevent redirects on nginx when domain in host header does not match domain in request url?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have nginx running on my home server at keepsecret.ddns.net. When I request e.g. keepsecret.ddns.net/foo/ it returns to me keepsecret.ddns.net/foo/index.html. So far, so good.

Now I am trying to treat my home server as an upstream server. In front of that upstream server is a remote proxy server at www.mydomain.com. When I request e.g. www.mydomain.com/foo/index.html, it is returned to me no problem. However, when I request www.mydomain.com/foo/, nginx first issues a 301 redirect so that I then get sent to keepsecret.ddns.net/foo/, revealing my home IP Address :(

I have no idea why nginx behaves this way. My only guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the domain in the request host header does not match the domain in the request url.

Questions in summary:

- Why does nginx do this?
- How can I prevent nginx performing this redirect so that I always remain on www.mydomain.com?

Here is the salient part of my config for reference:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}


server {

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name keepsecret.ddns.net www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keepsecret.ddns.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keepsecret.ddns.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = keepsecret.ddns.net) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

        server_name keepsecret.ddns.net www.mydomain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGINX will be doing an internal redirect to the index.html file in all cases, but it seems to get externalised when the server_name does not match the primary server_name. I suspect that changing the server_name order so that your public (proxied) name is first may get rid of that behaviour.

The alternative would be to focus on the reverse proxy, and take a look at proxy_redirect to make the reverse-proxy rewrite location headers for you.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try to get round to this this weekend. I'm using AWS-API-Gateway REST API for the proxy which, unfortunately, does not seem to provide much/any detailed control on the proxy server config.